# AS3 User Profile Management Database?

Tags: ios, database, actionscript-3, content-management-system, profile

I'm building an iOS app using Air for iOS. I want to add a user signup/log-in feature. Is there a website/service that can handle the backend of this? Is it just a matter of learning MySQL and doing everything on my own? I've searched all over the googles and have come up with zip. I'm probably not using the correct search terms. I need something that can manage user profiles. I hope that makes sense.

Anyway, any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much!
Tony

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in many different ways, i've always written my own communication code.

You can use:

- PHP/MySQL and call PHP pages with a URLRequest and get an XML/JSON as response.
- AMF for PHP or Zend passing optimized serialized objects that mantains their type using an RPC ( i prefer this method).
- SOAP and expose a service that you consume through WebService Class in AS3.